# Parallelize two independent loops

Tags: parallelization

```
tab = Table[Random[], {10^7}];
Block[{sum = 0, sum2 = 0}, Do[sum += tab[[i]], {i, Length[tab]}];
   Do[sum2 += tab[[i]]^2, {i, Length[tab]}];
   {sum, sum2}]
```

In the above code, the two do loops are independent of each other. I want to parallel execute the two loops. I tried

```
tab = Table[Random[], {10^7}];
Block[{sum = 0, sum2 = 0}, Parallelize[Do[sum += tab[[i]], {i, Length[tab]}];
   Do[sum2 += tab[[i]]^2, {i, Length[tab]}];];
   {sum, sum2}]
```

but it doesn't work. How can I parallel execute these two loops in different Kernels? The two functions of summation can be different too. For ex, if I want to $\exp(\text{tab}[[i]])$.

P.S.: I know there is a better way to sum a list of random numbers. I summed the list using loops to test the speed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one solution. It uses `$KernelID` which, if you one has two kernels, will typically have values `1` on one kernel, `2` on the other:

```
(* setup *)
SeedRandom[1];
tab=Table[Random[],{10^7}];

(* parallel *)
With[{tab=tab},
  ParallelEvaluate[
      Switch[$KernelID,
            1, sum=0;Do[sum+=t,{t,tab}];sum,
            2, sum=0;Do[sum+=t^2,{t,tab}];sum,
            _, 0 (* do nothing on other kernels *)
      ],
      DistributedContexts->None]]
```

**Discussion.** The data is sent to the kernels using `With`. The `DistributedContexts->None` makes sure that nothing else is sent around without you knowing. To make different definitions on different kernels, we use `Switch[$KernelID,...]`.

I use this kind of approach when I want to control precisely what is to be done on which kernel, as in OP's question. Clearly, this means that I the programmer am responsible for [load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)). Some other commands in the [`Parallel`-family](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ParallelComputing.html) provide automatic load balancing, which will be the right choice in some situations, please see the answer by @LukasLang.

Comment: A good solution, but if I change the function of the sum, this solution is not valid. I want to know if running two Do loops in two different kernels is possible.

Comment: Yes, this looks good. The only thing is my pc has 4 Kernels. So the Switch function for only two arguments doesn't work. Only if I put 4 arguments, it gives the correct result.

Comment: Dear @sslucifer, I edited my answer again, so that there are no problems with more than 2 kernels. I hope you don't mind, just trying to keep things simple for future viewers.

Comment: instead of not doing anything on the remaining kernels you could start exactly as many kernels as you need. See documentation of `LaunchKernels` and maybe `CloseKernels` for how to achieve that...

Comment: Don't use $KernelID. It is neither guaranteed to start at 1, nor be contiguous.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I would do it using `ParallelMap`:

First, make your two evaluations truly independent by wrapping `Block` around them separately instead):

```
SeedRandom[1];
tab = Table[Random[], {10^7}];
{
 Block[{sum = 0}, Do[sum += tab[[i]], {i, Length[tab]}]; sum],
 Block[{sum = 0}, Do[sum += tab[[i]]^2, {i, Length[tab]}]; sum]
 }
(* {5.00075*10^6, 3.33394*10^6} *)
```

You can now wrap the evaluations in `Hold` to prevent them from evaluating on the main kernel (here done using `Hold/@Unevaluated@{...}`), and then map `ReleaseHold` over the list using `ParallelMap`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
tab = Table[Random[], {10^7}];
ParallelMap[ReleaseHold,
 Hold /@ Unevaluated@{
    Block[{sum = 0}, Do[sum += tab[[i]], {i, Length[tab]}]; sum],
    Block[{sum = 0}, Do[sum += tab[[i]]^2, {i, Length[tab]}]; sum]
    }
 ]
(* {5.00075*10^6, 3.33394*10^6} *)
```

The advantage of this approach is that it is trivially extendable: It works with any number of available kernels and any number of available expressions. To fine tune how the expressions are distributed, you can use the `Method` option of [`ParallelMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelMap.html).

#### Side notes

I am assuming your code is a toy example, so I didn't mention it above, but here are some things I would improve about the code:

1. Use [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) instead of [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) to properly localize the `sum` variable (notice also that this takes ~12.8s on my PC):

   ```
   AbsoluteTiming@{
     Module[{sum = 0}, Do[sum += tab[[i]], {i, Length[tab]}]; sum],
     Module[{sum = 0}, Do[sum += tab[[i]]^2, {i, Length[tab]}]; sum]
     }
   (* {12.8127, {5.00075*10^6, 3.33394*10^6}} *)
   ```
2. Don't use `Do` if you can avoid it. Here, the loop is easily written using [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) (note how this is also significantly faster, taking only ~8.2s):

   ```
   AbsoluteTiming@{
     Sum[tab[[i]], {i, Length[tab]}],
     Sum[tab[[i]]^2, {i, Length[tab]}]
     }
   (* {8.22215, {5.00075*10^6, 3.33394*10^6}} *)
   ```
3. The sum is in fact so trivial in this case that you can use [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) (notice the insance speedup, it now only takes ~0.035s, a 350x improvement):

   ```
   AbsoluteTiming@{
     Total[tab],
     Total[tab^2]
     }
   (* {0.0353386, {5.00075*10^6, 3.33394*10^6}} *)
   ```

As noted above, I am aware that your actual code is probably more complex. I just thought I'd mention some improvements, in case some of them apply to your actual code.

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by @user293787 is correct. However, one needs only two kernels for the code to work. If one has four kernels like my pc,

```
With[{tab = tab}, ParallelEvaluate[sum = 0;
                    Switch[$KernelID,
                    1, Do[sum += tab[[i]], {i,Length[tab]}],
                    2, Do[sum += tab[[i]]^2, {i,Length[tab]}],
                    3, Null,
                    4, Null];
     sum, DistributedContexts -> None]]
```

Using this solution, I have been able to find an alternate solution.

```
ParallelTable[
     Piecewise[
          {{Block[{sum = 0}, Do[sum += tab[[i]], {i, Length[tab]}]; 
              sum], j == 1}, 
          {Block[{sum = 0}, Do[sum += tab[[i]]^2, {i, Length[tab]}];
              sum], j == 2}}], {j, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: I am glad you were able to adapt it to your case. Here are two alternatives to what you did. Alternative I: You can use `LaunchKernels[2]` to launch only two kernels, even if you have more available. Alternative II: You could also use something like `Switch[$KernelID,1,...,2,...,_,Null]` where `_` means all kernels except $1$ and $2$.

Answer (score 2):

The first reason this doesn't work is that the variables sum and sum2 are not synchronized with the parallel subkernels. You can modify the corresponding variables in the subkernels all day long and the result will not be visible in the master kernel.

The second reason is that the ; operator (CompoundExpression) explicitly requires sequential evaluation. So, your first loop is always run before the second one.

Parallelize[] will go inside the CompoundExpression and actually parallelize the first loop, then the second one, but for reason 1 above, this is pointless.

Given that you also need to distribute 10^7 values to all your kernels, you will not gain any meaningful insights from this timing experiment.

To parallelize a sequence of independent evaluations, you can put them into a list, and

```
Parallelize[{eval1, eval2, ...}]
```

will send those evaluations to different parallel subkernels and wait for all of them to finish.

So, a working example would first distribute the definition of tab (once), then
run the the two loops independently with local copies of the sum variables:

```
DistributeDefinitions[tab]

In[7]:= Parallelize[{
  sum = 0; Do[sum += tab[[i]], {i, Length[tab]}]; sum,
  sum = 0; Do[sum += tab[[i]]^2, {i, Length[tab]}]; sum
 }]

Out[7]= {5.00124*10^6, 3.33458*10^6}
```